# Browser chrome, in child window, navigator.getGamepads() does not work

Tags: google-chrome, gamepad

I use window.open method to open a child window, and in that window I use navigator.getGamepads() to retrieve the gamepad handle, but the result is empty.

It is strange that when I use navigator.getGamepads() in the parent window, the result is not empty, and gamepad is correctly detected.

After this if I use navigator.getGamepads() in the child window, it worked... why ??

Is there anything about security strategy?

Comment: Grammatical cleanup to make the question clearer

Comment: In Chrome 74, it is a bug: https://crbug.com/949320